# Castly Dynamic Proxy - Get the target method's return value

Tags: c#, reflection, castle-windsor, castle-dynamicproxy

When proxying an object and intercepting a method using castle dynamic proxy, is it possible to get the return value of the target method? I have tried using the following methods,

```
object result = invocation.GetConcreteMethod().Invoke(instance, null); 

object result = invocation.GetConcreteMethodInvocationTarget().Invoke(instance, null);
```

This causes an infinite loop. I want to be able to get the return value of the original target method being proxied before calling Invocation.Proceed().

EDIT -- Fyi I got it to work by using Activator.CreateInstance, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to achieve the equivalent:

```
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(invocation.TargetType); 

invocation.MethodInvocationTarget.Invoke(instance, invocation.Arguments);
```

The problem is that this is simply a new un-proxied instance of the original object, whereas I want the original un-proxied instance itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
invocation.Proceed();

var returnValue = invocation.ReturnValue;
```

Comment: Always null for me...any thoughts?

Comment: it will be null if you call it before `invocation.Proceed()`. After all, something has to produce the return value